# ¿Cómo recorrer arreglo multidimensional (JSON) y mostrar en una tabla?

Tags: php, laravel, json, api

En mi controlador mando a llamar el resultado de la API, con JSON de esta forma:

```
 $responseBody = json_decode($resp->getBody());
    if($responseBody->code == "5400"){
      return  redirect()->route('cosco.index')->with('warning', '-No  encontrado');
    }
 return view('busqueda',compact('responseBody'));
```

En la vista usaba estos foreach y no podía mostrar la información:

```
{{-- @foreach($responseBody as $item) --}}
{{-- @foreach(json_decode($item->data, true) as $d) --}}
```

Solamente puedo a acceder al primer registro  (manualmente) y quisiera acceder y mostrar toda la información que me da la llamada a la API.

```
    
 <td style="color: #310f88e7;font-weight: bold"> 
            {{$responseBody->data->content->trackingPath->busqueda}}
            <input type="hidden" id="ImportBL" name="ImportBL" 
            value="{{$responseBody->data->content->trackingPath->busqueda}}">
        </td>
```

ESTO es lo que me da la llamada a la API

```
 +"code": 0
  +"message": "success"
  +"data": {#1438 ▼
    +"type": "busqueda"
    +"numberType": "both"
    +"content": {#1444 ▼
      +"itNumber": "N.A."
      +"actualbusqueda": array:2 [▼
        0 => {#1445 ▶}
        1 => {#1441 ▶}
      ]
      +"trackingPath": {#1430 ▶}
      +"busquedasStatus": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1429 ▶}
      ]
      +"doc_ext": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1448 ▶}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Utiliza `foreach` solo con los arrays: `actualbusqueda-busquedasStatus-doc_ext`

Comment: ¿Un foreach , por cada array?

Comment: Si, porque son datos diferentes. Por ejemplo, para sacar los datos de `actualbusqueda`, tendrias que hacer: `foreach( $responseBody->data->content->actualbusqueda as $item )`

Comment: Gracias! , funciono a la perfeccion.